# Linux: parser variable from set command to bash file

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I am trying pass a variable from the `set` command to a `bash` script.

```
$ set BeginTime=2021-10-11 2:23:00 & ./getBeginTime.sh
```

File `getBeginTime.sh`:

```
local getBeginTime=$(set | grep BeginTime)
echo "BeginTime : = $getBeginTime"
```

Please explain why `echo $getBeginTime` returns an empty string

Comment: `set` is not how you set variables in bash, and the `&` will make that happen in a background subshell anyway (so if it did set a variable, it'd only be set in the subshell, not your main shell).

Comment: I have a command like this : $ set BeginTime=2021-10-11 2:23:00 & ./getBeginTime.sh
and I want to get the BeginTime variable in the file getBeginTime.sh, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of misunderstandings in your code

1. Assign a variable directly, without `set`, remembering to quote the string being assigned if it contains spaces or other characters that are special to the shell (if in doubt, quote)

   ```
   BeginTime='2021-10-11 2:23:00'
   ```
2. Do not run the assignment as a child. Child processes cannot affect their parent. By running the assignment with `&` you are assigning the value in a child process which promptly exits, leaving the parent unchanged
3. The value hasn't been made available to the environment (using `export`), so to pass it to a script you should include it on the command line:

   ```
   ./getBeginTime.sh "$BeginTime"
   ```

   You can then pick up this value in your script as the first parameter:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   getBeginTime="$1"
   echo "BeginTime : = $getBeginTime"
   ```

   A better way of writing the `echo` statement would be to use `printf`. The `echo` command is non-standard across shells, and different implementations handle certain character sequences differently. On the other hand `printf` is much more standardised. Here the `%s` is a placeholder for the parameter corresponding to your `"$getBeginTime"` variable

   ```
   printf "BeginTime : = %s\n" "$getBeginTime"
   ```

If you really want to pass the value as an environment variable, this next section illustrates two approaches, but note that these are a much less common way of passing values around:

```
# Define an environment variable just for this invocation
BeginTime='2021-10-11 2:23:00' ./getBeginTime.sh
```

or

```
# Define an environment variable for the remainder of this session
export BeginTime='2021-10-11 2:23:00'

# You can now use it as many times as you want
./getBeginTime.sh
./getBeginTime.sh
```

In your code you would simply use `"$BeginTime"` as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods to achieve this:

**1. Using env variables:**

From a bash terminal, set the variable:

```
export BeginTime="2021-10-11 2:23:00"
```

and then from a very simple script, `test.sh` call the variable:

```
[ws] user test_directory >cat test.sh

echo $BeginTime
```

**2. By passing an argument:**

The script `test.sh` is now just:

```
[ws] user test_directory >cat test.sh

echo $1
```

and you call it with the argument:

```
[ws] user test_directory > bash test.sh "2021-10-11 2:23:00"
```